# In drools, how to search an object in ArrayList and add if not present

Tags: drools

I have following model classes defined -

```
class A {
 ArrayList<Name> listOfNames
}

class Name {
 String first
 String last
}
```

When i receive a new Name instance, i would like to check if that exists in  instance of class A by comparing first/last fields for each Name in ArrayList.
Also would like to put that rule in excel if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of achieving this could be:

```
rule "test"
when
  $a: A($list: listOfNames)
  $n: Name()
  not Name( first == $n.first, last == $n.last) from $list
then
  modify($a){
    addName($n)
  }
end
```

Hope it helps,